# Validating Excel sheet contents

Tags: asp.net, excel, gridview

I have a asp page in which I am uploading an excel document from the user after which I display the contents of the excel sheet on a grid.
Is there any way I can validate the number of columns and the content of the columns(datatype and headers)?

Comment: :) See, I [told you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183290/opening-a-blank-excel-file-in-asp-net-and-corresponding-functionalities) there were complications in doing things this way using Excel. It's the wrong approach, and as I said before there are many other ways to transfer data back from the client to the server that are much easier to handle. You should look into getting "Pro ASP.Net 4 in C#" (can't get to Amazon from here for a link right now). The PDF copy is quite good to work with (although the printed one is too - the PDF is a lot lighter to carry around <g>).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Here's what you can do,

1. Depending on the format of your excel sheet (TSV, CSV or something else,) you can parse it.
2. Once parsed, you can run your verification checks against parsed data and confirm if data is exactly what you need.

If you can provide more details then I can guide you to a more accurate solution :).

Comment: This is amusing, but it's not really an answer.

Comment: kenwhite  .. i know it is getting complicated but i need to get it to work for all format eventually.
@Beenish Khan ...
I am using .xlsx and.xls extension if thats valid enough :P
THanks

Comment: Rather if someone  Could just tell me how to validate data in a datatable before I bind it to a grid and if there is invalid data , I need to mark/display the reason why it is invalid. That would also be great .

Answer (score 0):

The number of columns of Excel can be obtained by

```
UsedRange.Columns.Count
```

For headers, you can loop to verify one by one. For datatypes, you can use TypeName to verify - Say for example, if you loop to Cells(r, c), this is your datatype:

```
TypeName( Cells(r, c).Value )
```